# pyqt5 QTranslator() load not work after compile via pyinstaller but in pycharm run it's work

Tags: python, pyqt, pycharm, pyinstaller

I make **i18n** style practice on a little test project (use pyqt5), IDE is pycharm.

When I try pycharm run application then check the i18n switch language, it's work. But when I use pyinstaller compiler to a single or folder style 
the application does not work.

I guess maybe cause not load the qm file. The qm file content is about i18n language word string (on the sample project I use two language English and Chinese).

Even If I try to place the qm file on the same path with application, it still not load the qm file.

[My project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qWyNUo-adYW1403X1nrsRDUpKNcG6pIX/view?usp=sharing) (include ui file and ts + qm file).

I also make a video to record my operate : [my video demo](https://youtu.be/s3HmnSaQ9Bw)

Win64 + win32 + mac64, all got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following on Windows 10:

1. pyinstaller -Fw  --add-data Ui_main_en.qm;Ui_main_tw.qm main.py
2. ...\dist\main.exe     has moved      ...\QTranslator-pyinstaller\main.exe
3. Launched   ...\QTranslator-pyinstaller\main.exe

[image]